# How do I define the pulseaudio server during login?

Tags: pulseaudio, freenx

I frequently need to login from my desktop into my laptop using FreeNX, I am able to redirect the audio from session running on the laptop by setting the pulse audio default server using the "padevchooser" applet, setting it to the IP of my desktop.

Is there an easy way to achieve this from the freenx session login ? For example overriding the PA default server from the .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the current pulseaudio server to a X-session root window can be done with

```
pax11publish -e -S <pa-server>
```

This will export the currently used source, sink, and configuration of `<server-pa>` to the X11-session window.

Switching back to default is done by

```
pax11publish -e -r
```

We have however no experience and can not test how FreeNX does this and if that command is applicable.

Comment: I need the opposite behaviour, I need the local X-session to import the source/sink from a remote PA server.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I expected, looking into the source code from padevchooser I found that the server can be set from an environment variable, PULSE_SERVER, the following code on my ~/.bash_profile did it:

```
if [ -n "$NXSESSIONID" ]; then
  export PULSE_SERVER="local_desktop_ip"
fi
```